# Null check before assigning value in property Linq lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
caseDto.ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var eElement in zakkennisgeving.extraElementen.ToList())
{
  if (eElement.Value != null)
    caseDto.ExtendedProperties.Add(eElement.naam.ToString(), eElement.Value.ToString());
}
```

How do I do this with lambda expression?

I've tried this

```
zakkennisgeving.extraElementen.ToList().Where(x => x.Value != null && caseDto.ExtendedProperties.Add(x.naam.ToString(), x.Value.ToString())));
```

But as `Dictionary.Add()` doesn't return anything so it's not a valid statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by chaining [IEnumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and [IEnumerable.ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods

```
caseDto.ExtendedProperties =
    zakkennisgeving.extraElementen
                   .Where(element => element.Value != null)
                   .ToDictionary(element => element.naam.ToString(), 
                                 element => element.Value.ToString());
```